# Add a link to a specific page in WordPress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that has a footer with some custom links. (child theme development)

I do not want to put them into another menu element, I just want it to link to a specific page, but I'm not sure how I can link it to a specific page if I don't know the title

Can I hook it to a tag or some other feature that I can attach to the page and link to that?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Why don't you want to setup another menu? It sounds like what you need to do is setup a menu and display it using a menu widget.

Comment: its a set of images, in a very specific setup, with properties added for them to function differently on mobile, etc. Theres only one thats a permalink to another page. To set up a menu and code the entire thing eels like overkill with just one button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`get_permalink()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) function.

Example:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 268 ); ?>">My link to a post or page</a>
```

Comment: what does the '268' stand for?

Comment: The integer ID for a post or page, or a post object.

Comment: if the page is named 'about' then i put that in there

Comment: Please follow that link above, it has all you want to know.